# If $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 27$ and $xy + xz + yz = 11$, then what is $x + y + z$ (all values positive)?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, systems-of-equations, quadratics

> Given that $x$, $y$, and $z$ are positive numbers and given that:
>
> $$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 27 \quad\text{and}\quad xy + xz + yz = 11$$
>
> What is the value of $x + y + z$?

---

I'm aware that one way to solve this problem is to square $x + y + z$ since $$(x + y + z)^2 = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 2(xy + xz + yz)$$ However, I'm wondering how you would solve this without the aforementioned shortcut?

Comment: No, its fine. $x+y+z$  is the square root of 49.

Comment: @Wuestenfux correct, but my question is how do you get to $7$ without using the shortcut I mentioned above

Comment: Which equals  to 7

Comment: No, it is not fine, we must know if the variables are non negative.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Good point. I should clarify that I'm assuming x, y, and z are positive

Comment: This is not a shortcut, this is a viable way of solving. You are not invoking very advanced mathematical results, you are only using fairly basic addition and multiplication.

Comment: @Martigan I guess then my question is, what are other viable ways of solving this problem other than the one I mentioned?

Comment: I don't believe. However, if you try to play around factorizing $xy+xz+yz$, very soon you will come up with squaring $(x+y+z)$, so I believe this a kind of natural solution (just try to define $A=x+y+z$ and define $yz$ in terms of $A$ and $x$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the suboptimal ways is to make a variable replacement. For example, $u=x+y+z$, $v=(x-y)\sqrt{3/2}$, $w=-(x+y-2z)/\sqrt{2}$. After the replacement:
$$
x^2+y^2+z^2=\frac{u^2+v^2+w^2}3=27,\qquad xy+yz+zx=\frac{2u^2-v^2-w^2}6=11.
$$
And we need to find the value of $u$.
Then we make replacement $s=u^2, t=v^2+w^2$:
$$
s+t = 3\cdot27,\qquad2s-t=6\cdot 11,
$$
and we need to find the value of $\sqrt{s}$. Equations above are linear. So we can find $s$, and then calculate $\sqrt{s}$.

Comment: It is 100% based on knowing the result beforehand  and using the squaring of $x+y+z$. Why not use directly this variable replacement :$u=x+y+z, v=x^2+y^2+z^2, w=xy+yz+xz$, then $u^2=v^2+w^2=(x^2+y^2+z^2)+2(xy+yz+xz)=49$

Comment: No, it's not. We know the symmetry between $x,y,z$, then we rotate the coordinate system so one of the axis aligns with $(1,1,1)$, then we see common term.